# Prefabs x coordinate of position is getting mysteriously updated after destroying and reinstantiating them

Tags: unity, c#, 3d, gui, visual-studio

#### Project brief

I am trying to make a gamified version of to-do where the player enters tasks and is rewarded with points and a tree grows with the progress.

#### What I am trying to do

I have a list of tasks (strings) which I am rendering them as a todo list on UI. I also have an input field to enter new tasks. I am rendering this list of todo(s) inside the content area of scroll's pane.

---

This is the screenshot of very first initialization of the screen. Observe how todo list is rendering flawlessly for the first time. (Ignore the scoreboard and tree, they are not the focus of this question)

[image]

---

This is the hierarchy window, notice how prefabs - named as 'Task' - are rendering inside the scroll view's content game object.

[image]

---

The screenshot below is the Transformation of Task prefab. **Notice the X coordinate of position. It's 0 which is what is required!**

[image]

#### The expected behaviour

Upon entering a new task, the tasks are re-rendered on the screen based on the string collection data (which is being used to store these tasks in code). Before re-rendering, all previous prefab objects will be destroyed and the new ones will be initialized inside the content area following the same positioning as the default ones `See: RenderTasks() in TaskController.cs`.

#### The problem

Upon entering a new task, old prefab objects are destroying as planned but all the re-rendered tasks are not appearing.

[image]
[image]

---

Although, the prefabs objects are being instantiated in the content area as usual but are not appearing on the screen.

[image]

because the **X coordinate of the position** of prefab object has this value of **-880** in it now!

[image]

This value is coming from the **width of scroll view game object.**

[image]

---

**I am unable to figure out how this value is being filled. It's a mystery! I even checked with Visual Studio debugger and it also showed me the intended value of x which is 0 till the last step of the function `RenderTasks()`**

---

Here's the code:

**TaskController.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class TaskController : MonoBehaviour {
    readonly StringCollection listTasks = new StringCollection();

    public GameObject task;
    public GameObject contentAreaTasks;
    public GameObject inputField;

    void Start() {
        listTasks.Add("Read a book");
        listTasks.Add("Clean attic tomorrow");
        listTasks.Add("Write 3 pages of descriptive writing");
        listTasks.Add("Go to shopping");

        inputField.GetComponent<InputField>().onEndEdit.AddListener(CreateTask);
        RenderTasks();
    }

    void CleanUp() {
        foreach (GameObject prefab in GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("PrefabTask")) {
            Destroy(prefab);
        }
    }
    void RenderTasks() {
        CleanUp();

        for (int i = 0; i < listTasks.Count; i++) {
            GameObject prefab;

            float defaultY = -24.0f;
            float factorY = -56.0f;
            float y = (defaultY + (i * factorY)); // Y Co-ordinate of each subsequent task

            // Instantiate task prefab and attach it to 'content' area (game object) of 'ScrollPane' UI component
            prefab = Instantiate(task, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            contentAreaTasks.GetComponent<RectTransform>().SetPositionAndRotation(Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
            prefab.transform.SetParent(contentAreaTasks.transform, false);

            // Render prefab content:
            prefab.transform.Find("Text").GetComponent<Text>().text = listTasks[i];

            // Render pefab's transformations
            prefab.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchorMin = new Vector2(1, 1);
            prefab.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchorMax = new Vector2(1, 1);
            prefab.GetComponent<RectTransform>().pivot = new Vector2(1, 1);
            prefab.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta = new Vector2(800.0f, 40.0f);
            prefab.GetComponent<RectTransform>().position = new Vector3(0.0f, y, 0.0f);
            prefab.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition = new Vector3(0.0f, y, 0.0f);
        }
    }

    public void CreateTask(string task) {
        listTasks.Add(task);
        RenderTasks();
    }
}
```

**Task.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Task : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject toggle;
    public GameObject progressionController;

    void Start() {
        progressionController = GameObject.Find("ProgressionController");
    }

    public void OnTaskStatusChange() {
        bool status = toggle.GetComponent<Toggle>().isOn;
        string command = status ? "task_finished" : "task_unfinished";
        progressionController.GetComponent<ProgressionController>().UpdateProgress(command);
    }
}
```

**Please help in finding out the reason why it's being filled as -880 and how can I fill up the correct value which should be '0'?**

Comment: Here's the link to GitHub repo: https://github.com/thisisabhinay/todo-treehouse/

Comment: Have you tried using `anchoredPosition`? Any difference?

Comment: @DMGregory Thanks! `anchoredPosition` fixed the issue. Still, don't know how all this happened in the first place. Can you please explain it?

Comment: I won't be able to explain it today, but hopefully someone else can post an answer with more detail.